# SwiftUI: How to use NSSearchToolBarItem on macOS 11?

Tags: swiftui, toolbar, macos-big-sur, nssearchtoolbaritem

I watched the WWDC video "Adopt the new look of macOS" where they introduced NSSearchToolBarItem in Swift at 11:32 in the video.

This is exactly what I need to do but how do I add this search to my toolbar in SwiftUI?

There are lots of complex examples but they all seem to be written before this new API. There must be a simpler way?

```
import SwiftUI

var listItems = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]

struct ContentView: View
{
    
    @State var select: String? = "Item 1"
    @State var searchText: String = "hello"

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            NavigationView
            {
                List
                {
                    ForEach((0..<listItems.count), id: \.self)
                    {index in
                         Label(listItems[index], systemImage: "briefcase")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            .toolbar
            {
                Button(action: {})
                {
                    Label("Upload", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
                TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

There doesn't look to be an obvious way to do this using `NSSearchToolbarItem` directly but, looking into that class, it's using an `NSSearchField` under the hood which is relatively easy to use in SwiftUI using `NSViewRepresentable`:

```swift
struct SearchField: NSViewRepresentable {

    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSSearchFieldDelegate {
        var parent: SearchField

        init(_ parent: SearchField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
            guard let searchField = notification.object as? NSSearchField else {
                print("Unexpected control in update notification")
                return
            }
            self.parent.search = searchField.stringValue
        }

    }

    @Binding var search: String

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSSearchField {
        NSSearchField(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateNSView(_ searchField: NSSearchField, context: Context) {
        searchField.stringValue = search
        searchField.delegate = context.coordinator
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

}
```

You can then use this hosted view directly inside a `ToolbarItem`:

```swift
ToolbarItem {
    SearchField(search: $filter)
        .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: .infinity)
}
```

You may wish to fiddle with the dimensions a little (in the `.frame()` call) to match the exit platform-native dimensions but this seems to match pretty closely how Notes.app looks.

Search toolbar item in Notes.app:

[image: Screenshot showing search toolbar item in Notes.app]

Search toolbar item from the example code above:

[image: Screenshot showing search toolbar from example code]